# Javascript: String comparison for inside character issue

Tags: javascript

Small problem here. I have this challenge below.

Christmas is coming, and Santa has a long list to go through, to find who deserves presents for the big day. Go through a list of children, and return a list containing every child who appeared on Santa's list. Do not add any child more than once. Output should be sorted.

Comparison should be case sensitive, and the returned list return only one copy of each name. "Sam" and "sam" is allowed, but "sAm" and "sAm" is not.

Here's my **code**

```
function findChildren(santasList, children) {
    children.forEach(child => {
        santasList.forEach(s => {
            if(child.toLowerCase() === s.toLowerCase()){

                var longerLength = Math.max(child.length, s.length);
                for(var i = 0; i < longerLength; i++){
                    if (child[i] !== s[i]){
                        console.log(child);
                        return i;

                    }
                    console.log(child);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

    });

}

let santasList = ["Tom", "Errol", "Sam", "mistyMay","Peter","Jennifer", 
"macMerphy"];
let children = ["Errol", "Peter", "jennifer", "mistymay", "MacMerphy"];

findChildren(santasList, children);
```

This prints;
Errol
Peter
jennifer
mistymay
MacMerphy

But I believe it should print;
Errol
Peter
jennifer
MacMerphy?

Where's the fix?

Comment: In the question, it is written `Comparison should be case sensitive`. Then why are converting the name to lower case before comparing?

Comment: If the comparison is case-sensitive, then output should be `Errol` and `Peter` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of

```
if (child.toLowerCase() === s.toLowerCase()) {
```

**comparison was happening in a case-insensitive manner**.

Also, you can improve your code (**currently with O(N^3)**) further by using `filter` and `includes`

```
function findChildren(santasList, children) {
  return children.sort().filter( s => santasList.includes( s ) );
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function findChildren(santasList, children) {
  return children.sort().filter( s => santasList.includes( s ) );
}

let santasList = ["Tom", "Errol", "Sam", "mistyMay", "Peter", "Jennifer",
  "macMerphy"
];
let children = ["Errol", "Peter", "jennifer", "mistymay", "MacMerphy"];

console.log(findChildren(santasList, children));
```